# How can I display dates on the x axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, jupyter

I have daily data from 1994 Jan 1st - 2000 April 30th. I have the dates in datetime format, but when I plot a line plot with time on the x axis and the variable on the y axis, matplotlib prints out way too much on the x axis. How do I fix this issue with plotting dates?

I have done this so far:

```
# get the proper dates 
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

# jan 1st 1994 - april 30th 2000
start_dt = date(1994,1,1) 
end_dt = date(2000,4,30)

dates = []

for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    dates.append(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    #print(dt.shape)
    
dates = np.array(dates)


random = np.random.rand(dates.size)

plt.plot(dates,random)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I plot the dates so you can see the xticks?

Comment: if your x-axis is a datetime object and you use seaborn to plot, it will automatically handle the date labels for you.

Comment: I just tried sns.lineplot but still the x axis looks messed up... could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from necessary imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
```

The first thing to correct is the way you create your source data:

1. Use *Pandas* instead of *Numpy* (although some *Numpy* methods are still needed).
2. Since *Pandas* has its native date/time type (*datetime64*), use just it, instead of plain pythoninc *datetime*.
3. Create the source data as pandasonic *Series*.

You can achieve it the following way:

```
np.random.seed(1)    # To get repeatable results
dates = pd.date_range('1994-01-01', '2000-04-30')
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(dates.size), index=dates)
```

Then a remark concerning the image: Since you have **daily** data, you should print
only every n-th point, e.g. `s[::20]`. Otherwise the image will be not readable.

And to get image with dates, you can run e.g.:

```
plt.plot(s[::20])
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=[4,7,10]));
```

Things to note:

- **Major** *x* ticks (years) are printed in this case by default.
- I added **minor** *x* ticks (quarters) calling *set_minor_locator*.
- Rotation of *x* labels is not required, but I thought it is a
  nice feature. If you don't agree, remove `plt.xticks(rotation=30)`
  from the above code.

For the above source data I got the following image:

[image]

Comment: I was doing something similar and could not get it to work but this line worked for me ```plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())```